# Keyword not supported: 'data source' in ASP.net Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

I've been poking my brain around for a few days trying to figure this out.

I'm using winhost to host a SQL Server and I've looked up quite a few similar questions with the same issue but they all seemed to have some formatting error that was their issue.

What's wrong with my connection string?

```
<add name="ContactsDb"
     connectionString="Data Source=tcp:s10.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=DB_84426_webdevct;User ID=DB_84426_webdevct_user;Password=***********;Integrated Security=False;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException {"Keyword not supported: 'data source'."}. No inner exception.

Comment: In Provider, Have you tried System.Data.SqlClient. Check this MSDN URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much. I feel like an idiot. -_- I thought for Entity Framework automagic databases I needed to use the EntityClient.

Comment: A quick question, for each DbContext, do I need a new MSSQL database? Or can I connect several DbContext's to the same connection as long as I provide them with different names?

Comment: I think You can use same connection..

Comment: Just tried. I can indeed use the same connection.

Answer (score 11):

I had to change the provider name to System.Data.SqlClient from System.Data.EntityClient. I was mistaken in thinking I needed the EntityClient for the automagic powers of Entity Framework when connecting to an external SQL Server database. Thank you Paresh J.